# Howto auto-mount windows-partitions using /etc/fstab

Tags: windows, ntfs, fstab

Hello what do I have to write in the file "/etc/fstab" to get my windows-partition (/dev/sda3) automatically mounted on startup ?

I get this error-message (clicking on the bookmark for the partition in nautilus):

```
    Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 1: helper failed with:
  Unprivileged user can not mount NTFS block devices using the external FUSE
library. Either mount the volume as root, or rebuild NTFS-3G with integrated
FUSE support and make it setuid root. Please see more information at
http://ntfs-3g.org/support.html#unprivileged
```

My fstab looks like this:

```
> # /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid -o value -s UUID' to print the universally unique identifier
# for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name
# devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
/dev/sdb6       /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/dev/sda3   /media/Jonas    ntfs    rw,auto,users,nls=utf8,umask=007,gid=46  0  0

# swap was on /dev/sdb7 during installation
UUID=9dcdfad2-4e66-416e-bf68-142afe23fa0b none            swap    sw              0       0
```

I created the folder /media/Jonas and the partition is /dev/sda3.
What did I wrong ?

#### Solution: After rebooting, it worked well. Strange.

Comment: could you post the output of ls -la /media/Jonas ? you can try sudo chown root:plugdev /media/Jonas

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assume you are sure about:
- Your created directory is /media/Jonas (with uppercase J)
- Your ntfs partition is /dev/sda3 (you can find this out by issuing `sudo blkid`)

My fstab uses a simpler form:

```
/dev/sda3   /media/windows  ntfs    defaults    0   0
```

You may change your "rw,auto, ...." to "defaults"

Comment: It works for me only with UUIDs of devices from `sudo blkid` instead of /dev/DEVICE_NAME.

Answer (score 7):

I will add a little more info to the subject.

If not installed, I recommend to install `ntfs-3g` to allow `r/w` the ntfs partitions.

```
apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

Also, to make the install '*device independent*', use the UUID received from the `blkid` utility instead of referencing a physical device.

```
root:~ blkid
...
/dev/sda1: SEC_TYPE="msdos" LABEL="boot" UUID="140A-14B7" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="0009bf4f-01"
/dev/sda2: UUID="f24a4949-f4b2-4cad-a780-a138695079ec" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="0009bf4f-02"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="Western Digital" UUID="1C0EBC7A0EBC4F10" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="0002f5f9-01"
...
```

then, as usual, create a mounting point, for example `\wd` and edit `/etc/fstab` inserting the following line:

```
..
UUID=1C0EBC7A0EBC4F10  /wd  ntfs-3g  defaults  0 0
..
```

you can try to mount the new device without reboot with `mount -a`.

To avoid data corruption, if your need to remove the device, make sure you `umount` (`umount /wd` in this sample).

Answer (score 0):

While I generally recommend disabling fast startup on Windows 8, sometimes even that won't solve, in that case I used:

```
 sudo ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sda2 /path/to/mount
```

In my case /path/to/mount was my personal folder on /media, /dev/sda2 was my windows partition

Comment: I really wish I didn't have to do this all the time, but it seems Windows creates the hiberfile no matter how I setup it.

Comment: On my Windows 10 this doesn't happen anymore.