# Data partition not listed when I want to open a file

Tags: partitioning, 18.04, mount, kubuntu, automount

Some software (Gwenview, Firefox,...) only show my system’s partition and not my data partition when I want to open a file. Only after I opened Dolphin (which lists them all), the other programs show them.

Is this a mounting problem (and how do I fix it?) or a problem inside the software? I never had this problem with previous Kubuntu-releases, only now with Kubuntu 18.04.

The `sudo blkid /dev/sda2` output (for the partition I want mounted):

```
/dev/sda2: UUID="08CDB5494B990AD2" TYPE="ntfs" PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="e3611ca5-02"
```

The `nano /etc/fstab` output:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=e995033f-8d76-4a63-9e94-6e860aa48c60 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Sadly, the instructions in this automount-link are beyond my horizon. To me it seems as if not all the info needed for the 'nano'-file are given at the blkid order... I might stick to always opening Dolphin first. Just don't understand why it worked with all the other versions and not in 18.04 ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening an unmounted partition in a file manager like Dolphin mounts it automatically in Ubuntu. In the context menu of the partition in Dolphin, you should be able to see the `Mount` or `Unmount` option based on its current status.

If your data partition resides on the internal hard disk and should be available always, you can automount it at startup. 
In your specific case, you can simply add the following line to the `/etc/fstab` file (edit it as superuser, e.g. `sudo nano /etc/fstab`):

```
UUID=08CDB5494B990AD2   /media/data   ntfs    defaults    0   0
```

Add this line below the line where `/` is defined. It doesn’t matter whether it will go above or below the `/swapfile` line. The number of spaces between columns doesn’t matter, too.

The second column (`/media/data`) says where the partition will be mounted. This must be an existing folder which is not used for anything else. If it has not been created yet, create it using the command:

```
sudo mkdir /media/data
```

Then reboot Ubuntu and your data partition should be mounted automatically.

See also:

- [How to make partitions mount at startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164926/how-to-make-partitions-mount-at-startup)
- [Howto auto-mount windows-partitions using /etc/fstab](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34731/howto-auto-mount-windows-partitions-using-etc-fstab)

Comment: Thank you, very nice of you. I will try that soon (at the moment I really need my computer and don't want to risk messing something up. Even with all the help it's a bit more than I usually interfere with the software).