# I have Ubuntu installed on my SSD. How do I get my HDD to work on Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I am dualbooting with Windows so would I need to make a partition on the HDD? If so, what should the partition type be? Linux Root Partition? Linux Home? If this is not the issue, then what should I do?

To elaborate on the issue I am having, I can open files on the HDD from nautilus, but if I try to open them from somewhere else, for example opening them directly onto VLC or uploading something from the HDD onto Plex, then the drive does not show up. The drive is currently called "Basic Data".

Comment: When opening drives with nautilus they get mounted with gvfs (old) or gio (new). [This is how to access them from somewhere else](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33480/how-do-i-navigate-to-a-samba-location-ive-mounted-in-nautilus-on-the-command-li). But you should think about letting the system mount the drive for you [using fstab](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34731/howto-auto-mount-windows-partitions-using-etc-fstab).

Comment: Is Basic Data NTFS or ext4? Better to be called Basic_Data or BasicData as often you have to escape spaces. Not having spaces avoids some hassles. If NTFS above link will work, but many alternatives on default parameters.https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab