# How to convert a mounted partition back to Primary partition in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount

I deleted Windows completely by doing a clean install of Ubuntu on the C drive, during installation it didn't ask me to do any partitions as per, but now what I see is that the Disk drive D is shown as a mounted partition, and whenever I click on the drive D the first time after boot it shows me that the drive is under preparation. Whereas if i click again, it opens the drive.
Is there any way that I can change the partition to a primary partition ?

I am attaching the screenshot of drives :

[image]

Also, I am attaching the proof that the D drive is a mounted partition, as after I click backspace after opening the drive it takes me back to some media folder.

Proof of mounted partition :

[image]

Comment: "D Drive" is a Windows convention really for a partition. If you have deleted Windows, you should not use NTFS as it requires chkdsk or defrag periodically which cannot be done from Linux. Post this: `sudo parted -l`. If 10TB drive it must be gpt(GUID) partition which has no primary, extended or logical partitions. Only one type, essentially then all are primary with gpt.

Comment: This is the output of `sudo parted -l`
[https://imgur.com/a/9A40JRk]

Yes, I deleted windows recently

Comment: @1nfern0 It is not clear what you mean by "change the partition to a primary partition". It would help if you explained in the question *exactly* what the difference is between what you have now and what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your D: drive is already a "primary partition" (see https://www.howtogeek.com/184659/beginner-geek-hard-disk-partitions-explained/ for an explanation of the term).

If you want your D: drive mounted in a particular location by default, you can set a default mount point by editing `/etc/fstab`. See [Howto auto-mount windows-partitions using /etc/fstab](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34731/howto-auto-mount-windows-partitions-using-etc-fstab) for more details.

Comment: Actually no, I checked in "disks" and it is showing hdd as mounted partition at /media/$USER/hdd
Here is the screenshot of it : https://imgur.com/a/DufAQ3O

Comment: If you click on a partition with file browser it will auto mount with defaults & using UUID or if labeled using label like hdd. You can mount it & link folders, but I really suggest backing up & reformatting as ext4. When you have NTFS issues you will have to download Windows to fix them. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk & https://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions