# keep two folders synced between two partitions on the same PC - Dual Boot (Windows, Linux)

Tags: dual-boot, windows, sync

So I have a dual boot system, Windows 10 and Linux (Ubuntu).

I need a solution to keep some folders completely synced between the two partitions.

I normally use **Syncthing** to keep files synced between my Windows partition and my Android phone. I can't keep my two partitions synced using Syncthing because it requires that both partitions must be on in order to establish the synchronization. I can do that (since I'm using two Operating Systems inside the same PC).

Any ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: You can mount the Windows partition while running Ubuntu.

Comment: @user68186 i would like to know how to automatically mount the windows partition everytime i launch the linux one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Howto auto-mount windows-partitions using /etc/fstab](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34731/howto-auto-mount-windows-partitions-using-etc-fstab)